# What do you call a person who collects branded things?

Tags: single-word-requests, epithet-requests

What do we call person who buys or collects branded things like shirts, shoes, cars etc...

Comment: A collector? ...

Comment: If he does it at gunpoint – a brandit.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Only buys things of certain brands? Only buys brand-names (of all things)? Or only buys things of one brand?

Answer (score 4):

[*Materialistic*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/materialistic) is the most apt term I can think of:

> **ma·te·ri·al·ism**: a way of thinking that gives too much importance to material possessions rather than to spiritual or intellectual things

The term *sneakerhead* also comes to mind, but describes nowhere near what you're trying to describe. From the related [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sneaker_collecting):

> A sneakerhead is a person who collects, trades or admires sneakers as a form of hobby. A sneakerhead may also be highly experienced in distinguishing between real and fake replica sneakers.

Comment: Consumerist would also work.

Answer (score 1):

I think that we can him/her a **'Fashion victim collector'**

Answer (score 1):

I would call that person a *brand slave* or a *brand whore*.

> [brand slave](http://pt.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=brand%20whore): someone who buys and prominently displays name brand products (or products that feature large corporate polos, e.g. Ralph Lauren's Big Pony) under the belief that such loyalty to a label or corporation is a cachet and brings prestige to their otherwise lack of taste, regardless of the actual quality or value of the product.

Comment: The term is unfortunately, a bit vulgar.

Comment: @user1068446 Indeed. But "brand slave" is not.

Comment: You can be materialistic and not care about brands.